# Add text with hidden id to a spinner

Tags: android

Before I store only text in a spinner.but the question is how i store the text with its persnal id into a spinner,where the text being seen by the user and the corresponding id being shown by the devloper.the id is hidden always..how this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by id being hidden, but I think this is what you are looking for. The id for the TextView inside the spinner is somewhere in this class `android.R.id` I think it is `android.R.id.text1` but I don't remember.